# Laravel Filter Records with empty relationship with pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-pagination

Hello I want to get the records that excludes relationships with empty values. I tried a lot of codes but did not worked out correctly. Here one of my tries:

```
$product= [];
        $product= Product::select('id','ref_num','eta','customer_id')
        ->when(count($customer_ids) > 0, function($q) use ($customer_ids){
             return $q->whereIn('customer_id',$customer_ids);
        })
        ->when(!is_null($ref_num_q_string) && $ref_num_q_string !=='', function($q) use ($ref_num_q_string){
            return $q->where('ref_num','like','%'.$ref_num_q_string.'%');
        })
        ->with(['customer' => function($q){
            $q->select('id','company_name');
        }])
        // ->whereExists(function($q){
        //     $q->select('id','product_id','total_amount')
        //         ->from('bills')
        //         ->whereColumn('bills.product_id','products.id');
        // })
        // ->whereExists(function($q){
        //     $q->select('id','product_id','total_amount')
        //         ->from('invoices')
        //         ->whereColumn('invoices.product_id','products.id');
        // })
        ->with(['bill' => function($q){
            $q->with(['bill_items']);
            $q->select('id','product_id','total_amount');
        }])
        ->with(['invoice' => function($q){
            $q->with(['invoiceServices']);
            $q->select('id','product_id','total_amount');
        }])
        ->has('invoice')
        ->orHas('bill')
        ->orderBy($sort_by,$sort_type)
        ->paginate(isset($per_page) ? $per_page : 50);
```

I use the "when" clause during the search filter.
If I have 1 "has" method it returns the correct values but when I added "orHas" there goes the issue, it returns the records matching the string but other unnecessary records are with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `orHas` and `orWhere` cause some problems for you here. These will cause an issue with the rest of your query, meaning none of your other criteria is considered. You will need to use a closure on your `->has()` similar to the following:

```
->has(function ($query) {
    $query->has('invoice')
        ->orHas('bill');
})
->orderBy($sort_by,$sort_type)
->paginate(isset($per_page) ? $per_page : 50);
```

Now you will only get results where a row either has an invoice or a bill.

Check out the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Thanks man...  I actually have error with "has" but I did it this way:
`->where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereExists(function($q2){
                $q2->select('id','shipment_id','total_amount')
                 ->from('bills')
                 ->whereColumn('bills.product_id','shipments.id');
            })
            ->orWhereExists(function($q3){
                $q3->select('id','product_id','total_amount')
                 ->from('invoices')
                 ->whereColumn('invoices.product_id','shipments.id');
            });
        })`

Thanks for saving the day.